# What's missing in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: web-development, php, .net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

I think that most people would agree that ASP.NET MVC is one of the better technologies Microsoft has given us. It gives full control over the rendered HTML, provides separation of concerns and suites to stateless nature of web.

The last version of the framework gaves us new features and tools and it's great, but... what solutions should Microsoft include in new versions of framework? What are biggest gaps in comparison with another web frameworks like PHP or Ruby? What could improve developers productivity?

What's missing in ASP.NET MVC?  Why is this missing feature important?  How do you do without it now?

Comment: Duplicate question exists at stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702336/whats-missing-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: It is, but there the topic was closed.. It was right, but here it fits..

Comment: This question does not meet enough of our six guidelines for constructive subjective questions.

Answer (score 3):

Compared to Ruby there is definitely a built-in ORM missing.

LINQ is though good but is somewhat limited. And Entity Framework 4 was released without *code-only* feature which made it pretty much non-existent to many developers.

So my vote is on *code-only* for EF4.

Comment: And, of course, "code-only" or rather *code-first* support in EF is coming. Based on postings in the ADO-NET Futures forum: targeting Q1 2011.

Comment: EF also lacks extensibility points: caching etc. And it is very complex in complex updating(Attach,Detach and so on). NHibernate is definitely better for its second level cache support.

Comment: Code first is already available http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx Also, if you have MVC3 you can use NuGet to get EF Code First into a project rather simply

Comment: @Jetti: It's not final just a CTP which makes it unsuitable for any production purpose.you can't use for anything serious.

Answer (score 1):

It would be awesome to have a tool like Rack or Thor. And more mature unobtrusive JavaScript support.

Answer (score 1):

Properly reusable AJAX components and an online gallery of controls that can be shared with other users. Building AJAX-heavy sites from scratch still takes too much time and results in complex and frail constructs of tightly-coupled server and client side code.

Declarative Web helpers are definitely a step in the right direction to make this possible, but unfortunately they aren't quite ready in MVC 3 yet.